# In IOS, iframe in a bootstrap modal can not scroll

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

I have an iframe inside a bootstrap modal body:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <iframe style="height:500px;"> </iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

When I try to scroll down the iframe here, nothing happens in IOS. (iphone and ipad) Conversely, it perfectly works in Android.

What adjustments should I make to fix this in IOS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` on `modal-body` for iOS. It seems to be a common issue.

[Source](https://davidwalsh.name/scroll-iframes-ios)

**EDIT** OP states that [this](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/14839) helped them find their solution.

Comment: It didn't work. Can it be a problem related to bootstrap, because other iframes can scroll well in IOS.

Comment: Check towards the end of [this](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/14839). It seems to be a known issue. One said use `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto !important;` and `overflow-y: auto !important;`